# want to access the image with random string and path would be image name in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

**Orignial Image URL** : http://192.168.18.8/project/images/1.jpg

**Required URL** : http://192.168.18.8/project/images/1/CsdefSWe.jpg

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do add your htaccess Rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This site is not a code writing service, you are supposed to show some initial effort.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?project/images/(\d+)/.+\.jpg$ /project/images/$1.jpg [END]
```

Or a more general variant which works for different "file name extensions":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?project/images/(\d+)/.+\.([^.]+)$ /project/images/$1.$2 [END]
```